# Why is this sqlite3 UPDATE giving a syntax error?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a function that drops some tables and reinitializes a new set which are working fine, then when it updates the existing table with the following:

```
self.cursor.execute('''UPDATE beers1 SET (beer_name, og, fg, beer_desc, ibu, glass_type, keg_size) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) where id=1''',("Beer", 1, 1, "Delicious!", 0, "Pint Glass", 640))
```

Which then gives me:

```
OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Any insight would be incredibly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Because you're using the incorrect syntax: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

Comment: The grammar doesn't permit such a construct: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL syntax for an UPDATE statement is either:

```
UPDATE beers1
   SET (beer_name, og, fg, beer_desc, ibu, glass_type, keg_size) =
       (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 WHERE id = 1
```

Or:

```
UPDATE beers1
   SET beer_name = ?, og = ?, fg = ?,
       beer_desc = ?, ibu = ?, glass_type = ?, keg_size = ?
 WHERE id = 1
```

You will need to check the SQLite3 manual to see which is supported by SQLite3.  The second is almost guaranteed to be supported; the first may not be.